# Creating a Circle upon clicking anywhere in the canvas - Javascript/Canvas

Tags: javascript

The current code I have has 3 balls that are moving within the canvas but I also would like to add code where clicking on the canvas will display another circle (stationary). I tried the below code but currently stuck with the error I'm receiving. I think it's got something to do with the draw(c1) function but unsure how to have it fixed.

```
<div id="butDiv">
  <input type='button' id='Begin' value='Start'>
  <input type='button' id='resetCanvas' value='Reset'>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas1' onclick="draw()"></canvas>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = 1050;
const height = canvas.height = 500;
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
let rq;

function random(min, max) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}
class Ball{
    constructor(x, y, velX, velY, color, size){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update(){
        if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            this.x += this.velX;
            this.y += this.velY;
        }
}
let balls = [];
const loop = () => {
    while (balls.length < 3) {
        let size = 35;
        let ball = new Ball(
            random(0 + size,width - size), random(0 + size,height - size),15,15,'yellow',size);
        balls.push(ball);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    balls.forEach((i,a)=>{
        i.draw();
        i.update();

    })
    rq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function getCursorPosition(canvas, c1) {
    // Gets click position
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('getcursorpos');
    return {
    x: c1.clickX - rect.left, 
    y: c1.clickY - rect.top
    };
}

function draw(c1) {
    getCursorPosition(canvas,c1);
    var pos = getCursorPosition(canvas, c1);
    var clickX = pos.x;
    var clickY = pos.y;
    var size1 = Math.floor((Math.Random() * 3) + 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(clickX, clickY, size1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

document.getElementById('butDiv').addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id === "Begin") {
      if (tgt.value === "Start") {
        loop()
        tgt.value = "Pause";
      }else {
          cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
          tgt.value = "Start";          
        }
    }else if (tgt.id === "resetCanvas") {
      cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
      ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);     
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a solution for you, I wrote everything you'll need in `/* */` comments.

However it will only work if the game is stopped or paused, because when your game is running your canvas is always refreshing and you don't save the new dots, hence they will disappear on the next frame.

```html
<div id="butDiv">
  <input type='button' id='Begin' value='Start'>
  <input type='button' id='resetCanvas' value='Reset'>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas1' onclick="draw()"></canvas>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = 1050;
const height = canvas.height = 500;
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
let rq;
/* otherwise it wont be passed */
canvas.onclick = (event) => {draw(event)};

function random(min, max) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}
class Ball{
    constructor(x, y, velX, velY, color, size){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update(){
        if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            this.x += this.velX;
            this.y += this.velY;
        }
}
let balls = [];
const loop = () => {
    while (balls.length < 3) {
        let size = 35;
        let ball = new Ball(
            random(0 + size,width - size), random(0 + size,height - size),15,15,'yellow',size);
        balls.push(ball);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    balls.forEach((i,a)=>{
        i.draw();
        i.update();

    })
    rq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function getCursorPosition(canvas, c1) {
    // Gets click position
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    /* clickX and Y does not exist use clientX and Y */
    return {
    x: c1.offsetX, 
    y: c1.offsetY
    };
}

function draw(c1) {
        /* Why would you call it twice? */
    //getCursorPosition(canvas,c1);
    var pos = getCursorPosition(canvas, c1);
    var clickX = pos.x;
    var clickY = pos.y;
    /* you had a typo here Random -> random */
    var size1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    console.log(clickX, clickY, size1);
    ctx.arc(clickX, clickY, size1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

document.getElementById('butDiv').addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id === "Begin") {
      if (tgt.value === "Start") {
        loop()
        tgt.value = "Pause";
      }else {
          cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
          tgt.value = "Start";          
        }
    }else if (tgt.id === "resetCanvas") {
      cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
      ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);     
    }
})
</script>
```

Edited version where it displays the dots even if the balls are moving:

```html
<div id="butDiv">
  <input type='button' id='Begin' value='Start'>
  <input type='button' id='resetCanvas' value='Reset'>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas1' onclick="draw()"></canvas>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = 1050;
const height = canvas.height = 500;
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
let rq;
/* otherwise it wont be passed */
canvas.onclick = (event) => {draw(event)};

function random(min, max) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}
class Ball{
    constructor(x, y, velX, velY, color, size){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update(){
        if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
            }
            if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
            }
            this.x += this.velX;
            this.y += this.velY;
        }
}
// dot class - sorry for thinking that the dot was a ball object, my memory is converges to 0 :(
class Dot{
    constructor(x, y, color, size){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }
 draw(){
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
    }
}
let dots = [];
let balls = [];
const loop = () => {
    while (balls.length < 3) {
        let size = 35;
        let ball = new Ball(
            random(0 + size,width - size), random(0 + size,height - size),15,15,'yellow',size);
        balls.push(ball);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    balls.forEach((i,a)=>{
        i.draw();
        i.update();

    })
    // this is the suff that draws the dots, if you want them drawn under the balls just paste this to the behinning of the loop function
    dots.forEach(dot => {
        dot.draw();
    });
    rq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function getCursorPosition(canvas, c1) {
    // Gets click position
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    /* clickX and Y does not exist use clientX and Y */
    return {
    x: c1.offsetX, 
    y: c1.offsetY
    };
}

function draw(c1) {
        /* Why would you call it twice? */
    //getCursorPosition(canvas,c1);
    var pos = getCursorPosition(canvas, c1);
    /*var clickX = pos.x;
    var clickY = pos.y;*/
    /* you had a typo here Random -> random */
    var size1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    dots.push(new Dot(pos.x, pos.y, "black", size1));
    /*ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    console.log(clickX, clickY, size1);
    ctx.arc(clickX, clickY, size1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();*/
}

document.getElementById('butDiv').addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id === "Begin") {
      if (tgt.value === "Start") {
        loop()
        tgt.value = "Pause";
      }else {
          cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
          tgt.value = "Start";          
        }
    }else if (tgt.id === "resetCanvas") {
      cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
      ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);     
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Will it be possible to have the canvas continue refreshing but the added dots will stay? I tried putting both functions getCursorPosition and draw (c1) inside the click event?

Comment: Yes it is possible! Hence the dots are ball objects you can simply add them to your balls array and display them together with the yellow ones

Comment: Could you show me how? I tried doing some changes, adding the draw(c1) to the balls array but it removes the loop of the animation itself.

Comment: I modified the last script for you, everything is explained in the comments.

I forgot to write code for the reset button, but in theory you should be able to empty the dots array and that should solve the issue. 

code: https://jsfiddle.net/f9rzLp2m/75/